# TPU Classifier InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CrossReplicaSum' with these attrs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, google-cloud-tpu

I have attempted unsuccessfully to implement an `Estimator`-based Tensorflow Model using the `TPUEstimator` API. It hits an error during training:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CrossReplicaSum' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels: <no registered kernels>
[[Node: CrossReplicaSum_5 = CrossReplicaSum[T=DT_FLOAT](gradients/dense_2/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1)]]
```

There's also a warning at the beginning, though I'm not certain it's relevant:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:CrossShardOptimizer should be used within a tpu_shard_context, but got unset number_of_shards. Assuming 1.
```

Here's the relevant part of the model function:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
"""A simple NN with two hidden layers of 10 nodes each."""
input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])

dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_layer, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())
dense2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense2, units=4)

reshaped_logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 1, 4])

onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=4)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=reshaped_logits)

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

    optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05))

    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

I'm attempting local CPU execution using `TPUEstimator` by setting the `--use_tpu` flag to `False`. The `TPUEstimator` is instantiated and `train` is called thusly:

```
estimator_classifier = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
        model_fn=model_fn, 
        model_dir="/tmp/estimator_classifier_logs",
        config=tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig(
            session_config=tf.ConfigProto(
                allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True),
            tpu_config=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUConfig()
        ),
        train_batch_size=DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE,
        use_tpu=False,
        params={
            'feature_columns': feature_columns  
        }
    )

    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

    estimator_classifier.train(
        input_fn=data_factory.make_tpu_train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE),
        steps=DEFAULT_STEPS,
        hooks=[logging_hook]
    )
```

What is the meaning of this error, and how can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

The context is not clear.

Are your running your job in Cloud TPU environment or some environment with TPU hardware?

1. If no, this is expected. TPUEstimator is designed to be used mainly for Cloud TPU environment, where the backend worker has all kernels linked into the Tensorflow server correctly. CrossReplicaSum is part the kernel registered for device TPU (not CPU).
2. If yes, did you set your master address correctly. According to the log, it seems your tensorflow session master does not have the TPU device in it. If you are running the job in Cloud TPU, you can do

   ```
   with tf.Session('<replace_with_your_worker_address>') as sess:
       print(sess.list_devices())
   ```

   you should see at least see a device like `"/<some_thing_varies_in_your_env>/device:TPU:0"`.

Comment: I'll edit my question to reflect the fact that I'm attempting local CPU execution _using_ `TPUEstimator` by setting the `--use_tpu` flag to `False`

Answer (score -1):

As per Tensorflow [Using TPUs guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_tpu#optimizer):

> The CrossShardOptimizer is not compatible with local training. So, to have the same code run both locally and on a Cloud TPU, add lines like the following:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
if FLAGS.use_tpu:
  optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(optimizer)
```